# Random array/list inside class which will remain constant in next iterations (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, random

I want to create tables and lists with random values inside class which will remain constant in next iterations (simpy package). Is there any way to do it?
Thanks in advance

I tried self.env.run<2 , but it's probably not how this works.

However, will this work (i'm talking about self.zestaw1), of course?

```
class Agent:
    def __init__(self, village): 
        self.village=village        

        strategia=[]   
        for j in range(village.liczbastr):
            for i in range(village.memorysize):
                strategia.append(random.random()) 
        sumy=[]
        for j in range(village.liczbastr):
            sumy.append(sum(strategia[i+village.memorysize*j] for i in range(village.memorysize))) 
        strategia1=[]
        for j in range(village.liczbastr):
             for i in range(village.memorysize):        
                strategia1.append(strategia[i+j*village.memorysize]/sumy[j]) 
        listypre=[strategia1[i:i+village.memorysize] for i in range(0, village.memorysize*village.liczbastr, village.memorysize)] 
        self.zestaw1=np.array(listypre) 



historia=[]            
        for i in range(2*self.memorysize):
            historia.append(random.randint(0,100)) 
        self.historia=historia 

   def histupdate(self): #funkcja aktualizujaca historie
        for i in range(2*self.memorysize):
            self.historia[i-1]=self.historia[i]
        self.historia[2*self.memorysize-1]=self.attendance()
        return(self.historia)

    def attendance(self): #funkcja zliczajaca obecnosc w barze
        attend=0
        for v in self.occupied.values():
            if v.do_baru():
                attend = attend+1
        return(attend)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about random values in lists and tables in a class that are randomized once in the beginning, (if this is not what you are asking then please clarify your question) then use **init**: here's a complete example code

```
import random

class Foo:

    def __init__(self):
         self.list_main = ["OneBob", "TwoBob", "ThreeBob"]
         self.list_var = random.choice(self.list_main)
         print(self.list_var)


Bob_Name1 = Foo()
```

if you run this it will automatically do **init**, this is useful for calculations that are done once (especially random)

Edit: (I saw your changes) Probably, try.

Edit 2: I modified the example code to this: (added change_init function and calling it)

```
import random

class Foo:

     def __init__(self):
          self.list_main = ["OneBob", "TwoBob", "ThreeBob"]
          self.list_var = random.choice(self.list_main)
          print(self.list_var)

     def change_init(self, new_name):
          self.list_main[1] = new_name
          print (self.list_main)


Bob_Name1 = Foo()
Bob_Name1.change_init("FunBob")
```

Above you see the second item changed to FunBob, you can put any almost thing in the brackets in the call method in change_init. I did this by adding a parameter. Through this is cool and simple, I do not recommend this to while loops due it resetting the item many times.

Comment: And do you happen to know what to do if i actually want to change a something in this constant table? I will update my first post in a minute (i'm talking about part historia=[]...) @Mureinik

Comment: You can change anything if  you can access it. Above I show a function that can do that, but you can simplify it to "Bob_Name1.list_main[1] = "I hate being called FunBob"